# GSON - Handling double curly brackets

Tags: java, json, gson, android

I would like to know how I can represent this part of a JSON file in a Java-POJO structure. The JSON file itself has a structure that I've never seen before:

```
"codeShares": [
        {
          "codeShare": {
            "airlineCode": "LH",
            "trackNumber": "9695",
            "suffix": ""
          }
        },
        {
          "codeShare": {
            "airlineCode": "NH",
            "trackNumber": "5350",
            "suffix": ""
          }
        },
        {
          "codeShare": {
            "airlineCode": "TP",
            "trackNumber": "8988",
            "suffix": ""
          }
        },
        {
          "codeShare": {
            "airlineCode": "UA",
            "trackNumber": "7212",
            "suffix": ""
          }
        }
      ]
```

If there weren't those "codeShare" tags each time but a "normal" array, I'd understand how to represent it in a POJO but as I tested, a List does not work. The size of the list matches the amount of "codeShare" tags in the file, but the actual values such as "airlineCode" etc. are always null. If it is not List<>, what do I have to take?

CodeShare-Class:

```
private String airlineCode;
private String trackNumber;
private String suffix;

    public CodeShare(String airlineCode, String trackNumber, String suffix) {
        this.airlineCode = airlineCode;
        this.trackNumber = trackNumber;
        this.suffix = suffix;
    }

    public String getAirlineCode() {
        return airlineCode;
    }

    public String getTrackNumber() {
        return trackNumber;
    }

    public String getSuffix() {
        return suffix;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return airlineCode + trackNumber;
    }
```

Kenta1561

Comment: There are tools for that: see http://www.jsonschema2pojo.org/ for example (use source JSON on the right)

Comment: Thank you! I found out that I have to create two classes for "CodeShare" :D

Answer (score -1):

Create another class which contains codeShare object.

E.g.

```
public class CodeShareWrapper {
    public CodeShare codeShare;

    public CodeShareWrapper() {}
}
```

Now response class will be as:

```
public class MyResponse {
    public List<CodeShareWrapper> codeShares;

    public MyResponse() {}
}
```

Use MyResponse with Retrofit or while de-serializing JSON response using `Gson`.

```
MyResponse = new Gson().fromJson(jsonString, MyResponse.class);
```